# Use Template Haskell to generate instance recursively

Tags: haskell, generics, template-haskell

In GenericPretty, there is an Out class with a default implementation by using GHC.Generic magic.

As you can see that I defined Person data type, and if I want to implement Out class I have to write 3 times manually since Person used Address and Names data types which should be also the instances of Out class.

I want to generate the instance declaration automatically with Template Haskell. The procedure seems simple.

#### 1, Generate instance A for Person and seek the types which are used to define Person.

#### 2, If the type used to define Person is not an instance A, generate it recursively.

However, gen function will not work. The code generation will not stop, I am not sure why. it could be the problem with mapM if you comment it out, the last line in gen will work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP, TemplateHaskell,StandaloneDeriving, DeriveGeneric, DeriveDataTypeable  #-}
module DerivingTopDown where 
import Language.Haskell.TH
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Data
import Data.Proxy
import Control.Monad
import Text.PrettyPrint.GenericPretty
import Data.List
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Person  = Person Names Address 
             | Student Names Address 
                       deriving (Show, Generic, Eq, Ord , Data,Typeable)
data Names   = Names String 
                       deriving (Show, Generic, Eq, Ord, Data, Typeable)
data Address = Address String 
                       deriving (Show, Generic, Eq, Ord, Typeable, Data)

{-
data T a b = C1 a | C2 b
instance (Out a , Out b) => Out (T a b)

([],[NormalC Main.Person  [(NotStrict,ConT Main.Names),(NotStrict,ConT Main.Address)],
      NormalC Main.Student [(NotStrict,ConT Main.Names),(NotStrict,ConT Main.Address)]])
-}
-- instance Out Address
-- instance Out Names
-- instance Out Person
---      class name -> type name, use a stateT to store a dictionary
gen :: Name -> Name -> StateT [Name] Q [Dec]
gen cla typ = do
    (tys, cons) <- lift (getTyVarCons typ)
    let typeNames = map tvbName tys
    let instanceType = foldl' appT (conT typ) $ map varT typeNames
    let context = applyContext cla typeNames
    let decltyps = (conT cla `appT` instanceType)
    isIns <- lift (typ `isInstanceOf` cla)
    table <- get
    if isIns || elem typ table -- if it is already the instnace or we have generated it return []
       then return []
       else  do
          dec <-  lift $ fmap (:[]) $ instanceD context decltyps []
          modify (typ:)  -- add the generated type to dictionary
          let names = concatMap getSubType cons
          xs <-  mapM (\n -> gen cla n) names
          return $ concat xs ++ dec
          --return dec -- works fine if do not generate recursively by using mapM

f = (fmap fst ((runStateT $ gen ''Out ''Person) []))

getSubType :: Con -> [Name]
getSubType (NormalC n sts) = map type1 (map snd sts)

type1 :: Type -> Name
type1 (ConT n) = n

tvbName :: TyVarBndr -> Name
tvbName (PlainTV  name  ) = name
tvbName (KindedTV name _) = name


applyContext :: Name -> [Name] -> Q [Pred]
applyContext con typeNames = return (map apply typeNames)
                         where apply t = ClassP con [VarT t]

isInstanceOf :: Name -> Name -> Q Bool
isInstanceOf ty inst = do 
                t1 <- conT (ty)
                isInstance inst [t1]

getTyVarCons :: Name -> Q ([TyVarBndr], [Con])
getTyVarCons name = do
        info <- reify name
        case info of 
             TyConI dec ->
                case dec of
                     DataD    _ _ tvbs cons _ -> return (tvbs,cons)
                     NewtypeD _ _ tvbs con  _ -> return (tvbs,[con])

-- pp =   $(stringE . show =<< getCons ''Person)

pp1 name = stringE.show =<< name

isi name = do
    t1 <- [t| $name  |]
    isInstance ''Out [t1]
```

Comment: Can you show which splice you are expanding? When I use `f` in another module, it recurses down to `GHC.Base.String` before encountering an unmatched case in `getTyVarCons`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some incomplete function definitions (e.g. `type1`, `tvbName`, `getTyVarCons`) and I am running into that.

I inserted a trace statement in `DerivingTopDown.hs` at the entry to `gen`:

```
import Debug.Trace
...
gen cla typ = trace ("=== typ: " ++ show typ) $ do
  ...
```

and then loaded this file into `ghci`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import DerivingTopDown
f
```

and got the following output:

```
=== typ: DerivingTopDown.Person
=== typ: DerivingTopDown.Names
=== typ: GHC.Base.String

th.hs:1:1:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      DerivingTopDown.hs:(80,17)-(82,68): Non-exhaustive patterns in case

    Code: f
Failed, modules loaded: DerivingTopDown.
```

So it recursed down to `GHC.Base.String` and then failed in `getTyVarCons` because the `dec` for this type is:

```
dec = TySynD GHC.Base.String [] (AppT ListT (ConT GHC.Types.Char))
```

which isn't handled by the inner case statement in `getTyVarCons`.

Comment: Thanks man. I suppose that it should not go this far, since String is already the instance of Out class. It should just return []. I will try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot man, just let getTyVarCons to return ([],[]) will work.